# Confusing about the overload resolution of map::erase()

Tags: c++

I'm reading Nico's *The C++ Standard Library 2nd edition* book. He shows me a example of the `erase()` function of `map` at page 343:

```
std:map<std::string, float> coll;
// ...
for (auto pos = coll.begin(); pos != coll.end(); ) {
    if (pos->second == value) {
        pos = coll.erase(pos);   // since C++ 11

        // C++ 98
        // coll.erase(pos++);
    } else {
        ++pos;
    }
}
```

And the [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/) say that:

```
void erase( iterator position );               // C++ 98
iterator erase( const_iterator position );     // C++ 11
```

My question is how can the overload resolution select the C++ 11 version in the previous example that return the iterator of last removed element? The type of `pos` is `iterator` in the example, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map<X>::iterator` is specified to be convertible to `std::map<X>::const_iterator`, so you can pass in the former to a function expecting the latter.

Overload resolution doesn't need to pick between those two functions as they are mutually exclusive: the C++98 one is not available in C++11 and vice versa.

Here are the versions of `std::map::erase` which are available in C++11, from N3337 standards draft `[map]/2`:

> ```
> iterator erase(const_iterator position);
> size_type erase(const key_type& x);
> iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
> ```

Comment: The C++ Standard Library book says that C++11 provides both this two version. How can I find testimonies to figure out whether you or he is right?

Comment: @Jekton added a quote from the standard.